# Which tool or plugin for Theissen / Voronoi polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.18, voronoi-thiessen

As I understand you can generate Voronoi polygons in QGIS (2.18.2) using the following approaches;

- Vector menu / Geometry tools /
- OR
- MMGIS plugin in

I also read [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87065/enabling-saga-in-qgis/202329#202329) that you could use SAGA as well. I'm trying to create a shapefile of the UK postcode units using the Voronoi method as discussed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60531/what-is-the-ideal-workflow-to-map-british-postcode-territories/235083#235083) and wanted to understand what the difference was between the different algorithms given that I'll be running it across ~1.7 million points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot QGIS GRASS Processing function v.voronoi. Don't think SAGA has a Theissen implementation in the QGIS Processing version.

The result of the different providers is basically the same. But the input a bit different.

- MMQGIS is the most simple, no buffering. Very fast
- QGIS Geometry Tools has a parameter for buffering point resulting in a larger voronoid if you use it
- GRASS v.voronoid being the most flexible will let you draw the buffer on the fly (select extent on canvas) and you can choose between lines and polygons as output.
- As @PEL writes there is a implementation in Spatialite. You don't need to hook up to a spatialite DB. Just use a virtual layer with the code from the [spatialite cookbook](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=tesselations-4.0). It seems more advanced since you can set the tolerance of how close points must be to be used in a Voronoi calculation. From the [cookbook](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=tesselations-4.0):

  SELECT ST_DelaunayTriangulation(ST_Collect(geometry))
  FROM italy_populated_places;

Answer (score 1):

Into QGIS, when you use a Spatialite DB, you could can use Spatial SQL to create Voronoi polygon. Here an example from spatialite : [Cookbook](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=tesselations-4.0). I did not perform any comparison with your previous tool.

Comment: A similar function can be used in a PostGIS database: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_VoronoiPolygons.html

Answer (score 0):

I found in practice the SAGA Thiessen polygons algorithm to be significantly faster on larger datasets (e.g. 1m points) compared to the GRASS GIS v.voronoi algorithm.